# Using Quantifiers to express "At Least Three"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am having trouble interpreting this quantified statement:

All prime numbers at least 3 are even.

This is the pre-defined predicates given:

Square(x): x is a square number

Prime(x) : x is a prime number

Even(x)  : x is an even number

This is what I thought of:

$$\forall n \in \Z (Prime(n) \implies \exists x, y, z \in \Z (Prime(x) \land Prime(y) \land Prime(z) \land Even(x) \land Even(y) \land Even(z)))$$

Comment: _"All prime numbers at least three are even."_ $\leftarrow$ What does this statement mean? There is only one even prime number. Or are you just trying to state this, in which case it would lead to a universal false.

Comment: I can hardly read your attempt... "For all integers $x$... if $n$ (*where did $n$ come from?*) is prime then there exist $x$ (*you already used $x$ outside of this*), $y$, and $z$ integers such that $x,y,z$ are all prime and $x,y,z$ are all even..." (*where did $n$ go on the right side?*)  What?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained more in detail. I am suppose to translate the sentence into logic statement.

Comment: As for the statement "*If $n$ is a prime and $n\geq 3$ then $n$ is even*" that would be $\forall n\in\Bbb Z~((n\geq 3)\wedge (Prime(n)))\implies Even(n))$.  Of course, this is a false statement... the true statement is that if $n$ is prime and $n\geq 3$ then $n$ is *not* even.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, should have read my answer before submitting. I edited my answer

Comment: The English sentence "All prime numbers at least three are even" seems to be saying that every prime number which is $\ge3$ is even. But your attempt looks like you are trying (unsuccessfully) to express the statement "there are at least three prime numbers which are even". Which is it? The latter statement could be expressed by $$\forall x,y\in\mathbb Z\exists z\in\mathbb Z(z\ne x\land z\ne y\land Prime(x)\land Even(x)).$$

Comment: @bof I have changed the questions, I did not know using three and 3 would have made a difference. The question states that "All prime numbers at least 3 are even", thus I interpreted it as what you said "there are at least three prime numbers which are even". Which I hope I have interpreted correctly.

Comment: @ngbjr That's a very poorly stated question then (not saying it's your fault if that's how it was given, just stating). It should have been, "All prime numbers that are at least 3 are even." or "There are at least three even prime numbers."

Comment: @Jared Yup, it just a question given to us, thus I do not know if it is meant to be ambiguous or not. But I take it as the later which you have mentioned in your comment. Just to make it clear, does my answer above matches  "All prime numbers that are at least 3 are even."

Comment: No for a few reasons.  First, it is not an implication so $n$ does not need to appear at all.  Next, you failed to emphasize that $x,y,z$ are distinct.  Without emphasizing that $x\neq y, x\neq z$ and $y\neq z$ nothing prevents them from all representing the number $2$.

Comment: As for the supposed ambiguity in the statement... in my opinion it can be interpreted as the first and *only* the first (*if $n$ is prime and $n\geq 3$ then $n$ is even*).  "*~All primes at least three~ are even.*"  Here, "*All primes at least three*" is the subject of the sentence.  Trying to interpret it as the second where "*at least three are even*" is referring to there being three separate variables who are even makes the statement as a whole not make grammatical sense.  "*All primes ~at least three are even~.*"  In this, the subject verb object structure of the sentence is broken.

Comment: Consider the sentence "*I have some shirts, at least three are blue.*"  Here, we separated this with a comma.  Next, the "*at least three are blue*" is a run-on sentence.  What preceded this was its own sentence complete with subject verb and object of its own.  "*I have some shirts.*"  In your statement the "*All primes*" does not function on its own as a sentence with a verb and object.

Answer (score 0):

$\exists x,y,z \in P: [x\neq y ~\land x\neq z ~\land y\neq z ~\land x,y,z\in E ] $

where $P$  is the set of prime numbers, and $E$ is the set of even numbers.

Comment: As I read the at least three I would write it as $\ge 3$, not that there are at least three of them.

Comment: @RossMillikan You seem to be contradicting yourself.

Comment: My point is that the prime is at least three, so I would write $z \ge 3$ instead of all the $\neq$s that you did.  They are different readings of the problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan The OP wrote, "All prime numbers at least 3 are even." This is grammatically incorrect. It probably should have been, "Of all prime numbers, at least three of them are even." I'm quite certain that they did NOT mean, "All prime numbers greater than or equal to 3 are even." I will say no more on this topic.